# cssClass attribute in lightning:overlayLibrary not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am looking to implement a large modal using lightning:overlayLibrary. Please see `.slds-modal_large` size option demonstrated [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/) for clarity. But I am having trouble getting the cssClass attribute to work. Can someone shed some light here please?

> COMPONENT c:modalContent:

```
<aura:component>    
    <lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"/>
    <lightning:button name="modal" label="Show Modal" onclick="{!c.handleShowModal}"/>
</aura:component>
```

> CONTROLLER JS:

```
({    
    handleShowModal: function(component, evt, helper) {
        var modalBody;
        $A.createComponent("c:modalContent", {},
                           function(content, status) {
                               if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                                   modalBody = content;
                                   component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({
                                       header: "Modal Header Goes Here",
                                       body: modalBody, 
                                       showCloseButton: true,
                                       cssClass: "myModalClass", /* This doesn't work? */
                                       closeCallback: function() {
                                           alert('Modal closed!');
                                       }
                                   })

                               }

                           });
    }
})
```

> STYLE:

```
.THIS .myModalClass{
     background-color: coral !important;
     width: 75% !important;
     min-width: 50rem !important;
     max-width: 150rem !important;
}
```

Comment: slds-modal_medium and slds-modal_large are global css classes, myModalClass is scoped to your modalContent component, so you have to write a more specific css class to modify the modal, I guess

Comment: So are you suggesting that cssClass: "slds-modal_large" should work? Because it didn't. And how do I tweak myModalClass to make it more 'specific'?

Comment: `cssClass: "slds-modal_large"`must work, can you disable cache on your org?, so the changes are reflected inmediatly, if you do not want to do that, refresh your browser until the changes are applied

Comment: fyi if you're using dx you can add `"disabled": ["S1EncryptedStoragePref2"]` under the `orgPreferences` property to disable caching :-)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is mainly corresponded to lightning component shadow DOM: all custom component's css classes are placed in DOM style as `.COMPONENT_NAME.CUSTOM_CLASS {...}`.

In the same time `lightning:ovelayLibrary` put modal panel outside your component shadow DOM. That's why if you need to add some custom css to this modal it is necessary to provide full path to your custom css:
at `showCustomModal()`:

```
cssClass: component.getName() + " myModalClass",
```

at .css file:

```
.THIS.myModalClass .modal-body { // myModalClass will apply to modal body
    ...
}
```

Please note, that `.THIS` and `.myModalClass` have to be concatenated without any spaces, because they are related to the same html tag.